# Is it possible to retrieve sum of square, df, F value and P value after using linear mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

I have complete randomized block design with 3 treatment levels (control, moderate, heavy thinning in forest) and 3 replicates for each treatments. I collected rainfall under the canopy called as Throughfall(response variable). It was collected by monthly and study conducted 3 years. we considered treatment and month as fixed, year and replicates as random effects. So I have in my spreadsheet 324 cells total (12 month* 3 trt* 3 rep * 3 year). I just would like to have an anova table including SS, df, F value and P value for both fixed and random effects. here below that is only for fixed effect and I would like to report random effects and interactions too. I could not find the code which I can apply. Also how can I apply pairwise comparison? So can anyone help me about that?
Thank you,

I run the code below:

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
library(Matrix)

test<-lmer( log ~ trt + as.factor(month) +trt*as.factor(month)+ (1| year )+ (1|rep)  , data=dataf,REML="TRUE")
AIC(test)
summary(test)
anova(test)


######results####

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: log ~ trt + as.factor(month) + trt * as.factor(month) + (1 | year) + (1 | rep2)
   Data: dataf

REML criterion at convergence: 885.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9667 -0.7787  0.1229  0.6077  2.5410 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 year     (Intercept) 0.009945 0.09973 
 rep2     (Intercept) 0.000000 0.00000 
 Residual             0.957992 0.97877 
Number of obs: 324, groups:  year, 3; rep2, 3

> anova(test)
Analysis of Variance Table
                     npar  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
trt                     2   0.656  0.3282  0.3426
as.factor(month)       11 203.506 18.5006 19.3118
trt:as.factor(month)   22   0.270  0.0123  0.0128
```

I applied linear mixed model for my study, I would expect to have anova table.

Comment: Hi Furkan Atalar, welcome to SO. You'll note that your question has been closed. This is because you need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. In your case, you haven't provided any data. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks

Comment: Also, SO is not a code-writing service so asking users to supply you code is considered off-topic. I realise it is difficult to find solutions when you are starting out, but regarding asking asking for help, you need to demonstrate what you have tried so far. Some further points: 1) some of your answer relates to methodology, which again is off-topic for SO, and 2) your post has multiple questions, and it should only contain one. Try to focus on one particular issue (with an MRE). If you then have any further questions, post them as new questions. Good luck!